# how get the selected text value from array session to another page

Tags: php, html

this is cart.php :

```
   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k) {   

    <form class ="align-left"name="form1" method="post" action="cartqty.php">
      <tr>
      <td><p><?php $k['products_title']; ?></p></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="product_qty[]" value=""/></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php $k['products_id']; ?>"/>   </td>
      <td><?php echo number_format($k['price'],2); ?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update">                 
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </form>
```

this is cartqty.php :

```
session_start();
$product_code   = $_POST["product_code"];
$product_qty    = $_POST["product_qty"];
```

How to get the select value of input text quantity so i can update the session value accordingly, i always get the last value of product_qty array.
    Pleas help!!

Comment: where is this "input text quantity"??\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close form tag inside foreach block like:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k) {   

<form class ="align-left"name="form1" method="post" action="cartqty.php">
  <tr>
  <td><p><?php $k['products_title']; ?></p></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="product_qty[]" value=""/></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php $k['products_id']; ?>"/>   </td>
  <td><?php echo number_format($k['price'],2); ?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update">                 
 </form>
}
?>
</table>
```